# How to solve credentioal error issue in next js next-auth?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

Using app routing.
The below file is routes file for next-auth:

```
import DataServices from "@/services/requestApi";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import queryString from "query-string";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        userToken: { label: "UserToken", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        if (typeof credentials !== "undefined") {
          try {
            const res = await DataServices.Login(
              queryString.stringify(credentials)
            );
            return {
              user: {
                ...res.data,
              },
            };
          } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error.response?.data.message);
          }
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, trigger, session, account, user }) {
      if (trigger === "update") {
        if (session) {
          token.user = session;
          return token;
        }
      }
      if (account?.provider === "credentials") {
        return { ...token, ...user };
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, trigger, user }) {
      session = token;
      return session;
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return baseUrl;
    },
  },
  debug: false,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 86400,
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
    error: "/",
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

This is how we are using axios:

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `${BASEURL.ENDPOINT_URL}`,
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${AuthToken}`,
  },
});
```

Facing Error mentioned below:

> POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/credentials 401 (Unauthorized)

In headers getting below code:

> Request URL:
> http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/credentials
> Request Method:
> POST
> Status Code:
> 401 Unauthorized

I have tried changing content type to application/json , faced same issue.